# Gacutil does not work correctly

Tags: c#

First I added all assembly to C:

[image]

I try add assembly via CMD and is written "assembly added" but it is not true. In CMD when I try delete this assembly CMD can not find it. I work in Windows 8.1 and assembly is written in .Net 4.5

[image]

Have you got any idea how fix this problem?

Comment: gacutil /u <Assembly Display Name>, not .dll name

Comment: gacutil /i uses an _assemblyPath_-type parameter, gacutil /u uses _assemblyName_. I'd guess you'd need the assembly name instead of the assembly file name with /u. See MSDN on gacutil parameters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: :/ yes gacutil /u work correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gacutil /u System.Windows.Forms.dll // wrong
gacutil /u System.Windows.Forms     // right
```

Comment: I will accept your answer but I have to wait 8 minutes.